# Firebase React - routing doesn't work on firebase emulator

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I've got problem with react routing on Firebase. In my app, routing works fine upon running app by `react-scripts start`, but when it comes to run it in firebase emulator, routing stop working - same thing happen after deploy.

Every url renders me home view (/).

Code:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Home from './views/Home'
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
} from 'react-router-dom'
import TermsAndConditions from "./views/TermsAndConditions";
import PrivacyPolicy from "./views/PrivacyPolicy";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path="/terms-and-condition" component={TermsAndConditions} />
                    <Route exact path="/privacy-policy" component={PrivacyPolicy} />
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Switch` component instead of `div`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Home from './views/Home'
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
} from 'react-router-dom'
import TermsAndConditions from "./views/TermsAndConditions";
import PrivacyPolicy from "./views/PrivacyPolicy";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/terms-and-condition" component={TermsAndConditions} />
                    <Route path="/privacy-policy" component={PrivacyPolicy} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: it doesn't work, same situation - render same view on all routes

Comment: Try to remove the `exact`  @Fifis